# Exporting .sql file from MSI

Tags: sql-server, windows-installer, installshield

I have an MSI file that contains several .sql script files, can anyone tell me if it is possible to extract these file and look at the content. I tried using orca to export the ISSQLScriptFile table, but the files were exported as .sql.ibd, which is useless.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't looked at this in a long time but as I recall it's all encrypted.

https://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?188927-Extract-packed-script-sql-from-msi

"For security, the script is encrypted and then stored in the MSI package."

Someone then mentions that you can intercept the SQL files from a temp directory while the installer is running.

MichaelU could weigh in if this is still true and if there are any other work arounds.

Comment: Thanks Chris, yup when i opened the ibd files in notepad or ssms i only see unreadable characters. I was able to grab a few scripts during installation, but it seems like they r only set to execute under certain condition if that make sense.

Comment: You might just want to let the installer setup the database from scratch and then use SSMS to export the resulting database to a script.  Probably a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the files are inside the MSI file in the sense of being in the internal CAB file, then do an "administrative" install, which is not an install at all. A typical command would be:

msiexec /a [path to msi file] TARGETDIR=[path to a folder where the files will go]

It extracts all the separate files to that location.

Comment: They go into a custom table.  They aren't authored into the File table.